# Fetch method Formpara Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest

this is my jersey server, REST api using java

```
    @POST
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Path("registration")
        public User register(@FormParam("username") String userName, @FormParam("password") String password) {

            boolean isOk = true;
            User newUser =null;
            List<User> userList = em.createNamedQuery("User.findAll").getResultList();
            for(User user: userList){
                    if(user.getUsername().equals(userName)){
                    isOk = false;
                }
            }
            if(isOk == true){
                newUser = new User();
                newUser.setUsername(userName);
                newUser.setPassword(password);
                super.create(newUser);
            }

            return newUser;
        }
```

I use javascript to POST new user to the server via formdata

```
  buttonLogin.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log('login');

  const  imgData = new FormData();
  imgData.append('username', 'newuser');
  imgData.append('password', '123');

  for (var p of imgData) {
  console.log(p);
}
  //
  let url = endPointUrl + `webresources/users/registration`;
  const myHeader = new Headers({'Content-Type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"});

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeader,
    data: imgData
  })
  .then(json)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
      });
});
```

My server did receive formparam but it is null object. I expect that the server will receive username: "newuser" and password "123" but server receive null object
I test server with postman and everything is ok. So I assume that the problem is javascript code. 
Could you show me what is wrong with my code. Thank

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue, but shouldn't `'Content-Type'` be `'application/json'` ? further, what the `.then(json)` after the `fetch` ? I don't see a `json` object anywhere

Comment: the server will return json object

Comment: `json` is an object you're passing to function `then`. I don't see where the server returns it, at least not in the code you've posted

Comment: @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) this will convert user object to json

Comment: Please read again what I wrote, you're not answering to the point.